# JQuery / AJAX: On Input Field change, create php session, and refresh current page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I have two input fields.  One is for show called business and the other is hidden called auto_search_id and goes to server.  I have already created an autocomplete functionality.  What I want to do is if the user starts typing and decides to click on an autocomplete list item which has already stored businesses, the page takes the id, sends it to update.php page to update the PHP Session id, and then refreshes the page with the current Session id.

Having problems figuring out the correct AJAX coding. My change function for the input field is not working.  It pulls up the autocomplete, but when an auto complete list item is clicked, it doesn't send the id and refresh a page. I still new to JQuery/AJAX, but think I am missing something in the on #auto_search_id change function but not knowing what.  Please Help...

Javascript / JQuery / Ajax

```
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#business").autocomplete({
                minLength: 2,
                source: function(request, response){
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "/autocomplete-pq.php",
                        dataType: "json",
                        data:'keyword=' + request.term,
                        success: function(data){
                            response(data);
                        }
                    });
                },
                select: function(event, ui){
                    $("#business").val(ui.item.label);
                    $("#auto_search_id").val(ui.item.value);
                    return false;
                }
            });

            $("#auto_search_id").change(function(){
                $.ajax({
                    type:'POST',
                    url:"/update.php",
                    data: { varname: reponse},
                    success:function(response){
                        location.reload()
                    }
                });             
            });
        });

    </script>
```

PHP

```
    <?php
        session_start();
        $_SESSION["id"] = $_POST["varname"];
        echo $_SESSION["id"];
    ?>
```

HTML

```
    <input type="text" id="business" name="jurisdiction" value="<?php echo $juristiction ?>" required>
    <input type="hidden" name="search" id="auto_search_id"  />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot reproduce the code but i see 2 things being wrong:

1 Calling `$("#auto_search_id").val(ui.item.value);` actually sets a new value of an input, however it does not trigger it's *change* event. You should trigger it like so:

```
$("#auto_search_id").val(ui.item.value).trigger("change");
```

2 You are trying to send a response (which is not available yet) to the server. A assume you want to send the hidden field value to the server.

```
$("#auto_search_id").change(function(){
  var newID = $(this).val();
  $.ajax({
    type:'POST',
    url:"/update.php",
    data: {varname: newID},
    success:function(response){
      location.reload()
    }
  });             
});
```

Comment: This helped out alot.  I knew I was mising something to get the hidden value sent to the server.  It works great, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

First you need the check if the change event is been called. Put an alert inside it. To maintain session, you need to pass it's id calling the parameter PHPSESSID, but it has some security implications, please read: http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.session-id.php